# When have you officially 'started' something?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

To say, I started playing Violin when I was 12 years years old: Does this imply that you have played Violin regularly since you were 12 years old?

Can you 'have still started playing Violin when you are 12 years old' if you play for 3 months, stop, and then pick up lessons again 3 years later?

What are some scenarios for 'I started doing ,  years ago' and what can change this?

Comment: If you started playing the violin when you were 12, nothing can change that fact. You may have stopped and started again 50 times, but you still 'started' when you were 12. This remains the case unless you live in a dystopian universe where they have discovered a means of changing what happened in the past.

Answer (score 2):

If you play for 3 months, stop, and then pick up lessons again 3 years later.

- [you take it up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+up) - *To begin again; resume*:
- E.g. Let's [take up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+up) where we left off. (TFD)

Alternatively, You start/initiate/learn playing again.

> **[initiate (TFD)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/initiate)** As a verb, initiate means to ***start***.

Also, I started playing Violin and I *officially* started playing Violin can carry different connotations.

If something's done **officially**, it's done **formally**, often with the backing of some kind of authority.

Answer (score 1):

> **START** *verb* (past tense: started; past participle: started)
>
> 1. come into being; begin or be reckoned from a particular point in time or space.
> 2. cause (an event or process) to happen.

To say that you started to play violin when you were 12 years old *does not* imply that you have been playing the violin continuously since that point in time, it only means that you ***began*** to (learn, study) "play" that musical instrument at that time.

You can say that you "started" any activity at any time. And you can also say that at some point in time after you "started," you stopped that activity.

Comment: It is noticeable that in American English, when you talk about playing a musical instrument, you will sometimes use the definite article and sometimes not. In one sentence above you do both, first saying *you started to play violin*, and later *playing the violin*. In such a sentence in Britain we would always employ the article. Is there any rationale as to when you do and when you don't in America?

Comment: @WS2 - Well, apparently no rationale in my case as I was unaware of it until you brought it to my attention. I might be unconsciously reverting to a more vernacular pattern at times as I translate thoughts to type. I wanted to mention tht New Englanders also employ the politism (what's that calld?), 'fair to middling.'